# Constructing a compiler for Cool language

Tags: flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am building a lex tool for the language Cool. A better definition of the language can be found here :http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/software/cool/cool.html 
I am having some trouble in compiling my code. There might be some error in line `#include <string>` and `#include <iostream>` as the error is showing in these lines. Is there any other way to include the string library? A part of my code is given below:

```
%{
#include <cool-parse.h>
#include <stringtab.h>
#include <utilities.h>
#include <string>
#include<iostream>

/* The compiler assumes these identifiers. */
#define yylval cool_yylval
#define yylex  cool_yylex

/* Max size of string constants */
 #define MAX_STR_CONST 1025
 #define YY_NO_UNPUT   /* keep g++ happy */

 extern FILE *fin; /* we read from this file */


 #undef YY_INPUT
 #define YY_INPUT(buf,result,max_size) \
 if ( (result = fread( (char*)buf, sizeof(char), max_size, fin)) < 0) \
    YY_FATAL_ERROR( "read() in flex scanner failed");

 char string_buf[MAX_STR_CONST]; /* to assemble string constants */
 char *string_buf_ptr;

 static int comment_layer = 0;

 extern int curr_lineno;
 extern int verbose_flag;

 extern YYSTYPE cool_yylval;

%}

/* ----- Definitions begin: */

DARROW          =>
DIGIT           [0-9]

/* ----- Definitions end. */
```

Comment: I was able to compile the code. Are you using the tools provided by the university to compile the code?

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling the generated lexer as a C++ program, or as a C program? If you actually use `gcc` and you don't change the extension of the name of the generated scanner, then the C++ headers won't be found.

On the other hand, the `#include` lines for your own headers should be written with `"filename"` rather than `<filename.h>`. The angle brackets indicate that the header files are library headers, and for library headers the directory containing the source file is not searched.